# Creating a text-based game GUI (c#)

Tags: c#, text-based

First off -sorry if text based is the wrong name, the closest example of what I mean is the football manager series (though obviously that's infinity more complicated than what I have planned!). Basically a turn based game where you each time period you can make a few decisions, you click "next [time period]" and see the result of those decisions and make some more decisions.

I'm struggling with how to create the GUI side of it (the maths/game engine stuff is sorted.

I can achieve the above with a single c# form, but rather than having every conceivable option on one single form it would be much cleaner to have a series of forms that you switch between using drop down menus/buttons. I've tried about using panels but it got messy pretty quickly!

So if there are any other ideas/methods out there, let me know!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include screenshots of what you have now?  Would two text areas with command-line approach work?  When one player is active, the other would be disabled.  You could then see the history of the commands.  >> move 1

Comment: Right now I can't get a screenshot sorted but it's easy enough to describe:

A label with "score"

Two buttons (plus and minus) which adjust the amount of money to be spent that week and a label which displays the amount.

A "Next Week" button which translates the amount of money spent to a score that week and updates the score label according to what the money spent was worth.

As the game gets more complicated there will be so many options that I'd like to be able to use multiple forms which you can switch between pages of these options.

Hope that helps!

Comment: "As the game gets more complicated there will be so many options that I'd like to be able to use multiple forms which you can switch between pages of these options."  You could use a **TabControl** where each Tab is a different "page" for your options.  It's easy to switch between them then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Panel]

So what i got here is a normal form.
Each panel p1 p2 p3 p.. can be set to visibel = false.
You can activate them bij pressing a button and set it to visible = true.

Maybe one of the idea's is to use the left panel for a kind of menu.
and set each click event for hiding and showing a panel.

Comment: Also you can do it like this:

You get one panel and set it to visible false and fill, you create everything in the panel as needed, when your done on that panel you set the dock to none and minimize it so it doesnt botter you anymore. bij click or changhing a comboboxitem/button you call it to visible and set it to this lik panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the kind of thing I mean! Will give it a go! Much appreciated